# Prism Unity interception error

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

PRISM = 6.3; Unity interception=5.3;

I am refactoring a class to remove crosscutting concerns using Unity Interception with PRISM viewModelLocator = true.

In Module I register the interface and class along with identifying an interceptor:

```
Container.RegisterType<ITaxViewModel, TaxViewModel>(
new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), 
new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>());
```

I run the application then press the tax button and I get the following error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException   HResult=0x80131501
> Message='Set property 'Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel'
> threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '14'.
> Source=PresentationFramework
>
> StackTrace:    at
> System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
> IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
> skipJournaledProperties,   Object   rootObject,
> XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
>
> at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader
> xamlReader,  Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject,
> XamlAccessLevel  accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
>
> at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream,
> ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
> resourceLocator)
>
> at FOO.Views.TaxView.InitializeComponent()
>
> in C:\FooControlLibrary\Views\TaxView.xaml:line 1
>
> Inner Exception 1: ActivationException: Activation error occurred
> while trying to get instance of type TaxViewModel, key ""
>
> Inner Exception 2: ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
> dependency failed, type = "FOO.VM.TaxViewModel", name = "(none)".
> Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
> ArgumentException - The type FOO.VM.TaxViewModel is not interceptable.
> Parameter name: interceptedType

---

At the time of the exception, the container was:

> Resolving FOO.VM.TaxViewModel,(none)
>
> Inner Exception 3: ArgumentException: The type FOO.VM.TaxViewModel is
> not interceptable. Parameter name: interceptedType

I'm not sure if PRISM can resolve the proxy created by Unity. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to use Unity 5.x with Prism 6.3? Because, that will not work. You can only successfully use Unity 5.x with Prism 7+.

Comment: I made a mistake and looked at NuGet Unity package on the left instead of the right.  The installed version is 4.0.1 for both Unity and Unity.Interception.

Answer (score 0):

I can without Exception.
Prism.Unity : 6.3.0
Unity.Interception : 4.0.1

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    Container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
    Container.RegisterType<jobsRepository>(new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
                                           new InterceptionBehavior<LogBehavior>());

    var jobsRepo = Container.Resolve<jobsRepository>();
    jobsRepo.GetJobs();
    return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
}
```

IInterceptionBehavior

```
public class LogBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public bool WillExecute => true;

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("# before: " + input.MethodBase.Name);
        var result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        Console.WriteLine($"# end:{input.MethodBase.Name}");
        return result;
    }
}
```